# Why is there a sign change for variables when going from primal LP problem to dual LP problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have this primal problem:
$$Z = -2x_1+2x_2+10x_3+4x_4+2x_5 \to \min$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & -2\\
-1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
x_5\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 3\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
$$x\geq0$$

I will use the vector notation to make formulas shorter. $Z = c^Tx$ with according values in vector $c$ and unknown variables in vector $x$. I will rewrite this system of equations as $Ax=b$. Here $x,\lambda, \mu$ and $b$ are understood as vectors and $A$ is a rectangular matrix. $x,\lambda$ and $\mu$ are some unknown vectors.

By definition, we can construct a dual problem by first constructing the Lagrange function $L(x,\lambda,\mu)$ of that problem, then taking the $\inf$ with respect to vector $x$, which would give us a dual function $g(\lambda,\mu) = \inf(L(x,\lambda,\mu))$.

$$L(x,\lambda,\mu) = c^Tx + \lambda^T(Ax-b) - \mu^T x$$
$$g(\lambda,\mu) = \inf (c^Tx+\lambda^T Ax - \lambda^Tb-\mu^Tx) = \inf((c^T+\lambda^TA-\mu^T)x-\lambda^Tb)$$
$$\mu\geq0$$
Infimum of a linear function with respect to $x$ means that the coefficient in front of $x$ must be zero for that infimum to not be $-\infty$.

So we can rewrite this as $g(\lambda,\mu) = -\lambda^Tb \to \max$, though this doesn't depend on $\mu$ anymore. Our constraint becomes:
$$c^T+\lambda^TA-\mu^T=0 \implies c^T+\lambda^TA=\mu^T\geq0 \implies -\lambda^TA\leq c^T$$

From here you can determine that $\lambda^T$ is a $(1\times2)$ vector because it has to be that way in order to match dimentions of our constraints $-\lambda^TA \leq c^T:(n\times2)*(2\times5)=(1\times5) \implies n= 1$, as well as match dimensions in $-\lambda^Tb$ of our dual function.

Now the part that I'm confused about is if you actually go and do the calculation with some unknown $\lambda$, you'll get a dual function and a system of inequalities that look like this:
$$g(\lambda) = -2\lambda_1-3\lambda_2 \to \max$$
$$\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1+\lambda_2\leq -2\\
-\lambda_1+\lambda_2\leq 2\\
-2\lambda_1-\lambda_2\leq 10\\
-\lambda_2 \leq 4\\
2\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 \leq 2\\
\end{matrix}$$

However when I checked the answer and used online tools to construct a dual to that problem, it seems like all the signs in both inequalities and function of the dual problem are flipped, as if there doesn't need to be a minus sign before the $\lambda$ vector.
$$g(\lambda) = 2\lambda_1 + 3\lambda_2 \to \max$$
$$-\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \leq -2$$
$$\lambda_1-\lambda_2 \leq 2$$
$$...$$
Did I do something wrong? Or why is it that the sign flip doesn't matter if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the primal constraints are equalities, the corresponding dual variables are free (unrestricted in sign).  So the sign flip is just a change of variable $\lambda = -\pi$.